# TextBox not showing TargetNullValue when cleared

Tags: wpf

I have a TextBox with the TargetNullValue set to "0.00".  On intial load the window shows 0.00 because the binding property is null.
Now here is where I'm confused:
If I change the value of the TextBox to anything other than 0.00 to include spaces, and then clear the TextBox, I get 0.00.  If the value of the TextBox is 0.00, and I clear the TextBox, I get an empty TextBox.  This occurs even if I always raise a PropertyChanged notification, even if the backing property value did not change.

```
<TextBox Margin="5" Width="100" MaxLength="6" Text="{Binding FeeToleranceLevel,
         Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
         TargetNullValue='0.00', 
         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
         Converter={StaticResource ToleranceLvlCapConverter}}"
         HorizontalAlignment="Left">

public string FeeToleranceLevel
{
    get { return _feeToleranceLevel; }
    set
    {
        if(_feeToleranceLevel != value)
        {
            _feeToleranceLevel = value;
        }
        RaisePropertyChanged("FeeToleranceLevel");
    }
}

public sealed class ToleranceLvlCapConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region Implementation of IValueConverter
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if ((value != null) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.ToString())))
            return null;

        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try it removing your converter? Just to make sure that is not the issue. When you say 'clear the textbox' you mean setting its backing property to null?

Comment: No - if i select the entire field, and hit backspace, for example.  With anything other than 0.00 in the field, the field will reset/display 0.00.  With 0.00 in the field, and highlight/backspace, the field is blank.

Comment: Could you paste your converter code?

Comment: Strange, I'm not able to reproduce it